# Background image from props does not work using styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled component which I pass a url to be used as a background image but it does not work. I've seen other similar questions but nothing has fixed it.

My styled component:

```
export const BackgroundImage = styled.div`
  background: ${props => `url(${props.background})`};
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
`;
```

I use it like this:

```
<BackgroundImage background="https://imageurl.jpg" />
```

When I look at the developer tools in the browser I get this:

[image]

So it looks like it has complied correctly but you can't actually see the image on the page.

Comment: what happens when you hover over the url in developer tools? does it say that it can't access the resource?

Comment: Nothing happens when I hover over the url in developer tools but when I copy the url from there and paste it into a new tab I can see it perfectly fine at the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it right now and I think the problem is here that `<BackgroundImage/>` - Component does not have any height?

As soon as i give it a height e.g. `height: 100vh;` it's working fine.